# Can't iterate python dictionary. ( 'list' object has no attribute 'items' on line 13 in main.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to iterate all elements in `map`(dictionary). But I'm getting this error. Why does it say `dict` as `list`? And how do we resolve this problem?

> 'list' object has no attribute 'items' on line 13 in main.py

```
def thirdfarthestdistance(arr,x):
  map = {}
  for elem in arr:
    # Storing {(5, -3), (distance, element)}
    map[abs(elem-x)] = elem

  map = sorted(map)
  count = 0

  for key, value in map.items: # I tried map.items() too but didn't work.
    print(value)
    # if count == 2:
    #   return elem
    count = count + 1

print(thirdfarthestdistance([-3, -2, -1, 4, 7], 2))
```

Comment: `sorted` returns a list. dicts are unordered mappings, they can't be sorted. Use a `collections.OrderedDict` instead. Also, `for key, value in map.items:` should be `for key, value in map.items():`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: No I tried items() too and it returns same error. You can try it on Code Playground (https://trinket.io/python/ffe3531e69)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in the sorted(...) method. From python documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted

You'll see that the method returns a **list**. Therefore, when you call

```
map = sorted(map)
```

You are actually converting your dictionary to a sorted list.

Off the top of my head, a better way of doing this would be getting a sorted list of the keys, and then referencing that. Something like

```
keys = sorted(map.keys()) 
print(map[keys[2])
```

Obviously this is not including validation on your initial array.

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` returns a list; you are replacing your `dict` with the list of sorted keys.

Instead, you just want

```
for key, value in sorted(map.items()):
```

which iterates over a list of key/value pairs sorted by key.